# Add custom metabox to media library images

Tags: images, metabox

Is it possible to add a custom meta box for the images of the media library?How I achieve this using `add_post_meta()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! Just follow [this guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) and make these changes:

- Hook into the [`add_meta_boxes_attachment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes_post_type/) action instead of the [`add_meta_boxes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes/) action
- In the [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) call, pass `'attachment'` as the `$screen` parameter
- Hook into the [`save_post_attachment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) action instead of the [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) action

And of course, make sure to customize the example code to your specific needs.

Comment: I will read your suggested links and try to apply the concept. After the implementation, how I will obtain the associated custom data of a metabox of an attachment?

Comment: You can get it using the [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function. It's used in the guide, under the [Getting values](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/#getting-values) section.

Comment: I've read the Getting value section, I need to pass the post id to the function, will the post id work instead of the attachement id that is related to the images?

Comment: Attachments are stored in the same database table, `wp_posts` by default, so you can use the ID of the attachment as the `$post_id` parameter.

Comment: Good answer, maybe outdated now, I had to use 'edit_attachment' instead of 'save_post_attachment' here.

Answer (score 0):

You may add metaboxes to attachments this way :

```
function add_image_attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields["copyright"] = array(
        "label" => "Copyright",
        "input" => "text",
        "value" => get_post_meta($post->ID, "copyright", true),
    );
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "add_image_attachment_fields_to_edit", null, 2);


function add_image_attachment_fields_to_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if ( isset( $attachment['copyright'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'copyright', $attachment['copyright'] );
    }   
    return $post;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "add_image_attachment_fields_to_save", null , 2);
```